# How to add href to dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am working on a asp .net MVC project where i need to add a dropdownlist. 
My requirement is on selecting the DropDown option it should redirect to a particular URL.

Below is my cshtml code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ChatDropDown", Model.ChatdropdownValList)
```

Here is how I am assiging value to the list:

```
viewModel.ChatdropdownValList = new List<SelectListItem>() {
            new SelectListItem(){ Text="Sales", Value="www.sales.com" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text="TechSupport", 
                                   Value=www.techsupport.com" }};
```

Is there any possible way to do this without using jquery?

Comment: I don't see any JavaScript in your question (let alone jQuery). In fact, it's not all that clear what you're asking.

Comment: You can use `onchange` event in `DropDownList` helper, but you need to show your current JS code even it's not working. Are you want to use vanilla JS e.g. `getElementById` or `getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: I tried with jquery and the below is my code:                            
       $(function(){
        $("#ChatDropDown").change(function(){
         var selectedOption = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        window.open(selectedOption);                                                                But in this case the URL is getting open in a nwe tab where as I wnt to open that in the same tab. And here i would like to mention that i dont have any anchor tag(<a>) now so I cant set the target.